# Value of $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(f\left(x,y\right)\right)$ at $(0,1)$

Tags: calculus

> $f\left(x,y\right)=e^{x+y}\left(x^{\frac{1}{3}}\left(y-1\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}+y^{\frac{1}{3}}\left(x-1\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}\right)$

What's the value of $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(f\left(x,y\right)\right)$ at $(0,1)$? There two solutions below. Why are the answers different?

**Answer 1:**

> $f\left(x,1\right)=e^{x+1}\left(x-1\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}$

> $\frac{\partial }{\partial \:x}\left(f\left(x,1\right)\right)=e^{x+1}\left(x-1\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+\frac{2}{3}e^{x+1}\left(x-1\right)^{-\frac{1}{3}}$

> so $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(f\left(0,1\right)\right)=\frac{e}{3}$

**Answer 2：**

> $\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{f\left(0+\Delta x,1\right)-f\left(0,1\right)}{\Delta x}$

> $=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{e^{\Delta x+1}\left(\Delta x-1\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}-e}{\Delta x}$

> $\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{e\left(\left(\Delta x-1\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}-1\right)}{\Delta x}$

> $=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{e\left(\left(1-\Delta x\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}-1\right)}{\Delta x}=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{e\left(1-\frac{2}{3}\Delta x-1\right)}{\Delta x}$

> $=-\frac{2}{3}e$

Comment: You can't substitute the value of variable before the differentiation of the function as you did in first answer.

Comment: @SarGe There is nothing wrong with the approach in the first answer, except for the notation in the final line.  Indeed, you can substitute the other variables --- that is, afterall, what partial derivative does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In answer 1 you mistakenly go from
$$\require{color}
f(x,1)=e^{x+1}(x-1)^{{\color{red}2}/3}
$$
to
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}[f(x,1)]=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}[e^{x+1}(x-1)^{{\color{red}1}/3}]
$$
(plus you forgot the exponential factor).

Doing it correctly would give answer 1 as
\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}[f(x,1)]&=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}[e^{x+1}(x-1)^{2/3}]\\
&=e^{x+1}(x-1)^{2/3}+\frac23e^{x+1}(x-1)^{-1/3}\\
\therefore\left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\right\vert_{x=0}[f(x,1)]&=e^{0+1}(0-1)^{2/3}+\frac23e^{0+1}(0-1)^{-1/3}=\dots
\end{align*}

Similarly, in answer 2, you forget the factor $e^{\Delta x}$ when you go from
$$
\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{e^{\Delta x+1}(\Delta x-1)^{\frac{2}{3}}-e}{\Delta x}$$
to
$$\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{e\big((\Delta x-1)^{\frac{2}{3}}-1\big)}{\Delta x}$$
when it is, in fact,
$$\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{e\big(e^{\Delta x}(\Delta x-1)^{\frac{2}{3}}-1\big)}{\Delta x}.$$

Comment: Sorry,it was a typo, but the answer stayed the same.@user10354138

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: You're right. I omitted $e^{\Delta x}$. I should have substituted Taylor $e^{\Delta x}=1+\Delta x$ for it.Thank you! @user10354138

Answer (score 0):

The first one is **wrong**!
You correctly have that $f(x,1)= e^{x+1}(x- 1)^{2/3}$
but the derivative of that is $f_x(x,1)= e^{x+1}(x+1)^{2/3}+ (2/3)e^{x+ 1}(x- 1)^{-1/3}$.

You incorrectly has "-" rather than "+".

Comment: Sorry,it was a typo.@user247327